# Ios - ionic - Cordova Plugin Media - getCurrentPosition - NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I’m trying to get getCurrentPosition()
i only get an error from Xcode

```
this.iosAudio_file.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    console.log("audio position: " + position);
 }).catch(_=>{
      console.log("position error: ");
 });
```

The error from Xcode:

```
2018-02-06 03:58:46.786217-0800 [2342:1572180] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Invalid number value (NaN) in JSON write
2018-02-06 03:58:46.789125-0800 [2342:1572180] exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: nan
```

package.json

"cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",

```
config.xml

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="^5.0.2">
         <variable name="KEEP_AVAUDIOSESSION_ALWAYS_ACTIVE" value="NO" />
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, should be fixed soon

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13852